# Need to query CloudWatch logs cross accounts via lambda using AWS SDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, sdk

I need to query CloudWatch logs cross accounts via lambda using AWS SDK

1. I deploy lambda that is written in typescript
2. Lambda deployed using cloudformation and have roles to read from two diffrent aws accounts (from lambda location and from secondary account)
3. at first I am executing

```
cloudWatchLogs.startQuery(startQueryParams).promise()
```

to get queryId

4. than using the queryId I am executing:

```
cloudWatchLogs.getQueryResults(getQueryResultsParams).promise()
```

to get log events that I need

at this point I am using the following params to get log events locally:

```
           <{
            const startQueryParams = {
                logGroupName: this.logGroupName,
                queryString: this.queryString,`your text`
                startTime: this.startTime,
                endTime: this.endTime
           };>
```

assuning that my lambda has the relavant security roles to query between two accounts
what should I do to run my code (Lambda) from account_A and to get logs events from account_B?
to get account_B token and to use that.

Answer (score 2):

For Lambda in account A to be able to use CloudWatch in account B you need to:

1. Configure your Lambda function's execution role to allow the function to assume an IAM role in account B.
2. Create a role in account B that allows interaction with CloudWatch. Modify the IAM role's trust policy to allow your Lambda function to assume the role.
3. Add the AWS Security Token Service (AWS STS) AssumeRole API call to your Lambda function's code.

More details: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-assume-iam-role/

AssumeRole JavaScript SDK example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/example_sts_AssumeRole_section.html

Comment: Thanks Anton. Checking